# Web browser not firing DocumentCompleted event

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to implement simple webpage screen capture program. When I was using my code on UI thread all seemed to work with no problems, but when I called method from non-UI threads I couldn't get WebBrowserDocumentCompleted event to fire any more. I also tried this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        wb.Visible = true;
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);

        while (wb.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                              new Action(delegate { }));
        }
```

Program just hangs in while loop, indefinitely. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not wait for the DocumentCompeleted event, you should start your Action when it fires (in the event handler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public void Start()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    wb.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
    wb.Visible = true;
    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate(url);
}

private void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if( (sender as WebBrowser).ReadyState == System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        // Do what ever you want to do here when page is completely loaded.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you in your quest.

Comment: I have exactly this implementation and my event won't fire.
I'm using the webbrowser into a STA background thread.

Comment: You should not create the WebBrowser in a background thread.  You can create it as part of the UI or in the Form-Shown event or somewhere similar.  Good luck.

Comment: I need it to be instantiated in background. I'm using it to render pages that use javascript/ajax for rendering results of a search, and since i'm delivering multithreading performance, the webbrowser msut be created in a bg thread =/

Comment: You need to create a thread, create a form with a webbrowser in it and run the message pump to make it work.  Look at this simple example http://dotnetbeyond.blogspot.dk/2011/10/multiple-ui-threads-in-winforms.html.  I have not tested it, but it seems simple enough.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant by "Run the message pump" but I had to call `Application.DoEvents()` to get the event to fire.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is unbelievable. After hours of searching and trying things, I found the answer.

In the properties of `webBrowser1`, I set the `AllowNavigation = false`.

If set to `false`, it only registers the `DocumentCompleted` event only ONCE, but when the `AllowNavigation = true` (which it is by default), the `DocumentCompleted` event is fired multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In your build output window, look for the below warning:

"*Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly*"

If you find this warning, ensure all assemblies use the same version of the conflicting Referenced assembly and recheck if WebBrowser delivers your events.